# Parenting to an array end cap

Tags: modifiers

I have an array with two different objects as the StartCap and EndCap. So far everything works fine.

Now, I want another object (let us call it ObjRight) to be offsetted from the EndCap object, so when I increase the Array Count, ObjRight will follow the EndCap as the array increase/decrease.

The easiest thing would be to just join the ObjRight with the EndCap but I need them to be separate objects where EndCap is ObjRight's parent.

Comment: You could use animation drivers

Answer (score 1):

Solution without drivers:
What about using a curve to define the length of your array ? You could then hook the last control point of your curve to your ObjRight. The solution isn't perfect as you would have a space between the OjRight and the Endcap but with a proper set up you could mask the problem (moving the ObjRight with fix increments snap to the grid for example).

Solution with drivers:
This solution (probably the best) would be to drive the ObjRight location (or an empty that you can use as a parent for ObjRight) by the array count.

Hope it makes sens. Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Drivers make more sense to me, easier to control. Thank you for the tip. I will try and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @MaxKielland if you find a solution please share it as an answer.

Comment: Yes of course :) If I can get it to work I will mark this as the right answer. I'm a little busy right now, bt when I get the time...